# Activity blinks after CustomTab closing

Tags: android, android-activity, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

I have activity with button. OnClick opens CustomTab:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
                builder.build().launchUrl(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MainActivity blinks with black after closing CustomTab. Why this is happening? How can I fix this?
The problem is reproduced for example by  Nexus 5X android 8.0, Pixel 2 android 8.0

[image: Activity blink gif]
[image: Black blink]

With custom animations:

[image: blink with custom animations]

Comment: Can you confirm if the issue still happens if you setup custom in / out animations? Here's an example on how to do it: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/blob/master/demos/src/main/java/org/chromium/customtabsdemos/CustomUIActivity.java#L157-L159

Comment: Yes, blink still happens with custom animations. I added gif to the question.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this matter?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find a solution

Comment: it looks like a problem inside CustomTab

Comment: I am still facing this issue when enter and exit animations are set. Did this fixed for you in latest jetback library ?@Strang6